# What is happening here with this function pointer

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have a function being passed to another function but I'm not sure why both of these work and don't produce any warnings.

```
typedef short (*COMP)(char  *, char *);

DATA *bst_get(BST *, char *, COMP);

short cmp(char *a, char *b)
{
    if (strstr(a, b))
        return 0;
    return strcmp(a, b);
}

// Both of these produce the same results
//     the difference is '&cmp' vs 'cmp'
data = bst_get(bst, "textA", &cmp);
data = bst_get(bst, "textA", cmp);
```

So which is the correct usage? Does it matter?

Comment: Normally you should use `&cmp`, but `cmp` is also accepted. Function identifier decays to pointer to the function.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: "Normally you should use `&cmp`" - Why that? using just the name is very well accepted.

Comment: This is what I said. If you want the address of something you must use `&something` for any thing, but for some special things (arrays, functions) the name of the object by itself represents an address...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmp` is an expression with "function type". Expressions with these types are (almost) always implicitly converted to an expression with the corresponding function *pointer* type, *similar* (*see note at end) to how expressions with array type are implicitly converted to pointers to the first array element. This implicit conversion is often called **decaying**, though this is not a term used by the C language standard (but by C++).

`&cmp` on the other hand makes the conversion explicit: Here you're taking the address of a function, thus receiving a function pointer.

So, bottom line: They're equivalent, and at least in C there's no practical difference between using one over the other.

The relevant part in the standard:

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type "function returning *type*" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning *type*".
>
> [N1570 §6.3.2.1/4]

Note: That means, being "explicit" all the times would mean writing function calls like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void) {
  printf("Awesome\n");
}

int main() {
  (&foo)();
  return 0;
}
```

*) *Important*: The similarity mentioned is that there's an implicit conversion happening. While `func` and `&func` yield the **exact** same result (value and type), `array` and `&array` yield **different** results (different pointer types). The reason is that `array` is implicitly converted to `&(array[0])`. So, repeat, the similarity is that there are implicit conversions happening. The actual conversions are different.

Comment: Using just the name of a function is exactly as explicit as using the `&` operator. A function call requires an _explicit_ parenthesis postfix operator.

Comment: @Olaf I don't really understand what you're trying to tell me. What I'm about is that `cmp` is an expression with function type, that (almost always) is (implicitly) converted to an expression with pointer to function type, as is done explicitly when using operator `&`.

Comment: " that (almost always) is" - when is it not? It is not like arrays. It is **only** called as a function if an **explicit** `(` follows.

Comment: Btw. `sizeof` and `_Alignof` are illegal for functions.

Comment: @Olaf The implicit conversion isn't happening when using the address of operator (which is then doing an explicit conversion), as be seen in the quote from the standard. That's why I put these parentheses, in all practical cases the conversion happens. Even in the case when calling a function: Actually, we're always calling (through) function pointers. The "like arrays" part is there because the conversion is similar, thus hopefully showing parallels to the reader.

Comment: No, they are **not** similar. `&func` yields **exactly** the same as `func` for a function. `&array` does not! And - as I wrote `sizeof(func)` and `_alingof(func)` are illegal, so only `&` is left. And - as I clarified - yields **exactly** the same as `func`. Actually, your statement "Actually, we're always calling (through) function pointers" is correct. So according to your logic, the "correct way was to call a function through `(&func)(...)` and use `funcPtr(...)` only for function pointers,

Comment: @Olaf Ah, is that what it's been about? What I mean with "similar" is that when using the expression `array` an implicit conversion (to a pointer to its first element) is done. The similarity is the implicit conversion, not that the resulting types of the plain expression and the expression prefixed with the address of operator would yield the same result (which, as you said, it doesn't for arrays, `&array` is a pointer to an array, not to its first element)

Comment: Remember this is read by beginners who take such laxness serious. There is already enough confusion about arrays and pointers. So we should be very precise about the terminology.

Comment: I'll try to make it more precise.

Answer (score 1):

In C, functions are converted to pointer to the function when used in expressions.
`cmp` and `&cmp` both here represents the address of function, therefore both are equivalent as a function argument to `bst_get`.